# Bat para ativar e desativar proxy

Tags: windows, batch, ip, proxy

Preciso de uma bat para ativar e desativar proxy já com os ips setados alguem pode me ajudar ?

Para ativar uso o seguinte comando:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f
```

Desativar:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
```

Preciso que ele ja ative com o ip e a porta que eu quero como faço isso?.

Comment: Windows ou linux? a opção de proxy do navegador? poderia detalhar mais a pergunta?

Comment: windows, todas as maquinas seriam no windows !

Comment: O que tentou até o momento ?

Comment: para ativar - REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f

Comment: para desativar - REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f

Comment: So que esse comando so ativa e desativa , preciso que ele ja ative com o ip e a porta que eu quero ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o Google Chrome, você pode usar as opções de linha de comando [`--proxy-server`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#proxy-server) para usar um servidor *proxy* especifico e [`--no-proxy-server`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-proxy-server) para conexões diretas.

A lista completa de opções de linha de comando pode ser visto [**aqui**](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Para o Internet Explorer você pode criar um arquivo `.reg` e colocar esse conteúdo:

```
Regedit4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyServer"="http://<proxyEndereco>:<porta>"
```

Veja mais detalhes [**aqui**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961).

Em *Batch* você pode fazer algo assim:

```
@echo off

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d <proxyEndereco>:<porta> /f
```

Comment: e o seguinte man esse exemplo em batch funciona mais ele nao entra ja com o ip e a porta ...

Comment: eu coloquei o proxyendereco e a porta ... 
ficou assim 
@echo off

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d <172.16.7.200>:<3128> /f
pause

Comment: blz agora funcionou vlw,sabe alguma forma de colocar exceções tbm ?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00**

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]

"ProxyOverride"="**AQUI AS EXEÇÕES.*;**"

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o mesmo esquema em apenas um VBS. Segue o script:
Após salve como vbs.

```
dim oShell
set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

if msgbox("PROXY [nome da organização], Habilitar?", vbQuestion or vbYesNo) = vbYes then
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\currentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer", "192.168.15.254:3129", "REG_SZ"
else
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"

End if

Set oShell = Nothing
```